# MYSQL Can't Insert Into mediumtext Column

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a script that will query an old database and pull the information from it, then push it to a new database (with a new structure).

My issue is that one of the tables in my old database has a column of `text` type. When I pull this text (which works) and try to push it to the new database (with a column that has the type of `mediumtext`) the query does not succeed.

Obviously there is some error with the query but for some reason my page does not output any errors.

**This question is more about what am I doing wrong vs. how do I output my errors to the page, but regardless, can anybody help me out? Thanks!**

PHP:

```
$grad5app = mysqli_query($grad5app_connect, "SELECT * FROM international");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($grad5app)) {
    $applicationId = $row[0];
    $toefl_hasTaken = $row[27];
    $toefl_hasReported = $row[28];
    $toefl_date = $row[2];
    $toefl_score = $row[3];
    $hasUSCareer = $row[4];
    $usCareerDetails = $row[5];
    $hasFurtherStudies = $row[29];
    $furtherStudiesDetails = $row[6];
    $hasHomeCareer = $row[30];
    $homeCareerDetails = $row[7];
    $financeDetails = $row[8];
    $usFriendsOrRelatives = $row[9];
    $usEmergencyContact_name = $row[10];
    $usEmergencyContact_relationship = $row[17];
    //$usEmergencyContact_contactInformationId = $row[];
    $homeEmergencyContact_name = $row[18];
    $homeEmergencyContact_relationship = $row[26];
    //$homeEmergencyContact_contactInformationId = $row[];

    echo $usCareerDetails;

    $grad5app1 = mysqli_query($grad5app_connect, "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE applicant_id = ".$applicationId." ");
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($grad5app1)) {
        $isInternationalStudent = $row1[132];

        mysqli_query($gradschool_application_2_connect, "INSERT INTO APPLICATION_International (applicationId, isInternationalStudent, toefl_hasTaken, toefl_hasReported, toefl_date, toefl_score, hasUSCareer, usCareerDetails".
        ") VALUES (".$applicationId.", ".$isInternationalStudent.", ".$toefl_hasTaken.", ".$toefl_hasReported.", '".$toefl_date."', ".$toefl_score.", ".$hasUSCareer.", '".$usCareerDetails."')");
    }
}
```

The variable `$usCareerDetails` is what is of type `text` and what needs to be pushed to a column of the type `mediumtext`. This query does not work, however, if I remove `usCareerDetails` from the query then it does successfully push the data.

Output of page:

`I'm gonna work in the USA for 2 years.`

The output is the `echo $usCareerDetails;` that is pulled from the old database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the query, but in the data. The `'` in `I'm` is destroying your query. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and you should be fine.